# Цикл не завершившись попадает в следующую итерацию

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Суть: Цикл перескакивает с начала выполнения retrofit2, где myList - это коллекция list.

UPDATE: В общем проблема в том, что запрос выполняется асинхронно и необходимо стопнуть хотя бы секунду пока запрос не получит ответ. Как можно остановить работу основного потока и поставить её на ожидание?

```
for(k=0;k<myList.size();k++) {

            retrofit2.Call<List<Zadachiofuser_response>> call = RetrofitClient.getmInstance().getApi().getzadachiCall(zaprosserver[0], zaprosserver[1], myList.get(k));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Zadachiofuser_response>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Zadachiofuser_response>> call, Response<List<Zadachiofuser_response>> response) {
                    List<Zadachiofuser_response> zadachiofuserE = response.body();
                    zadachasofdatesClass = new zadachasofdate[zadachiofuserE.size()];
                    String username="";
                    //region ПАРСИНГ и запись классов
                    for(int j=0;j<zadachiofuserE.size();j++){

                        String datestart = zadachiofuserE.get(j).getDatestart();
                        String dateend = zadachiofuserE.get(j).getDateend();
                        username = zadachiofuserE.get(j).getNameisp();
                        String zadachaname = zadachiofuserE.get(j).getNamezadach();
                        Toast.makeText(week_calendar.this, datestart+" / "+dateend+" / "+username+" / "+zadachaname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String[] Sdatetimeparse = datestart.split("T");
                        String[] Sdateparse = Sdatetimeparse[0].split("-");
                        int yeartemp = Integer.parseInt(Sdateparse[0]);
                        int monthtemp = Integer.parseInt(Sdateparse[1]);
                        int daytemp = Integer.parseInt(Sdateparse[2]);

                        String[] Edatetimeparse = dateend.split("T");
                        String[] Edateparse = Edatetimeparse[0].split("-");
                        int Eyeartemp = Integer.parseInt(Edateparse[0]);
                        int Emonthtemp = Integer.parseInt(Edateparse[1]);
                        int Edaytemp = Integer.parseInt(Edateparse[2]);
                        //  Toast.makeText(add_tabel.this,nameZadacha.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        zadachasofdatesClass[j] = new zadachasofdate(yeartemp,monthtemp,daytemp,Eyeartemp,Emonthtemp,Edaytemp,zadachaname);
                    }
                    userzadachiclass[k] = new userszadachi(myList.get(k),zadachasofdatesClass);
                    //endregion
                    // userzadachiclass[k] = new userszadachi(myList.get(k),zadachasofdatesClass);
                    //if(i==myList.size()) {stopper=1;}

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Zadachiofuser_response>> call, Throwable t) {
                    String a = t.toString();
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: В общем проблема в том, что запрос выполняется асинхронно и необходимо стопнуть хотя бы секунду пока запрос не получит ответ.

Comment: Может тогда лучше посылать синхронные запросы, раз асинхронность не нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно выполнять запросы последовательно, то вынесите цикл целиком в другой поток, например, AsyncTask'ом, и используйте call.execute() вместо call.enqueue(). Колбэки будут не нужны, обрабатывать ответ нужно будет в теле цикла

```
Response<List<Zadachiofuser_response>> response = call.execute();
if(!response.isSuccessful())
   continue;
List<Zadachiofuser_response> list = response.body();
```

пауза в секунду не даст вам гарантии поочередного выполнения, если один из запросов подвиснет он даже с секундной форой может выполнится после того, что вызывался за ним